# How to Start a Process in Session 1 from a Windows 7 Service

Tags: c#, windows-7, service

I have a service running in Windows 7.  In Windows 7 all services run in Session 0.  From that service I want to create an interactive user session (in a session other than Session 0) and start an application in that session.  My problem is that when I call LogonUser to start an interactive user session and then use CreateProcessAsUser to start the application the application ends up running in Session 0.

All of my code is C#.

Here is the relevant code:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool LogonUser(
    string principal,
    string authority,
    string password,
    UInt32 logonType,
    UInt32 logonProvider,
    out    IntPtr token);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(
    IntPtr hToken,
    string lpApplicationName,
    string lpCommandLine,
    IntPtr lpProcessAttributes,
    IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
    bool bInheritHandles,
    int dwCreationFlags,
    IntPtr lpEnvironment,
    string lpCurrentDirectory,
    ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
    ref PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

IntPtr token;
LogonUser("UserName", ".", "Password", 
    LogonTypes.Interactive,LogonProviders.Default, out token)

<code to impersonate user>
string hd = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%USERPROFILE%");

IntPtr envBlock = IntPtr.Zero;
CreateProcessAsUser(token, "PathToMenu.exe",
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS |CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
    "WinSta0\\Default", hd, envBlock, "Menu");
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: User856021, hello brother, if you have solved your problem then can you post the code for it? I am using windows 8 and running with same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tons of things can go wrong when trying to launch a process from a service in Vista/7. I would recommend that you start with [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/SubvertingVistaUAC.aspx) article and adapt it to your needs. I can tell you that I've used and modified the code in the article quite a bit, and it works. I'm sorry I can't show it to you because the modified code belongs to my company.

Comment: Matt - Thanks very much - I think this will get me going.  I had hoped to be able to handle the case with no user logged in, using LogonUser to create a user session.  This works just fine in WinXP but not in Win7 with Sessioin0 Isolation.

Comment: This helped me a lot... gave me a foundation of how to fix my problem. +1