# How to start a process in session 1 without using a service?

Tags: c#, windows-7, sessionid

I am using Windows 7 and I want to execute any application in session 1 from a C# code. Do I need to use a service to launch an application in session 1 from C# code?

Comment: There's nothing special about session 1; did you mean session 0?  What are you actually trying to do?  (If you aren't using a service, your code is probably *already* running in session 1, so the question doesn't really make sense.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question , I suggests you look here [How to Start a Process in Session 1 from a Windows 7 Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824170/how-to-start-a-process-in-session-1-from-a-windows-7-service?rq=1) for a possible solution.

Starting a session 1 program from a session 0 application in win7/vista seems to be explained in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a process in behalf of another user, you need the credentials of the account that's supposed to run the process.

If the process is instead intended to run with your actual credentials, then a egular exe and a new entry in the registry can do the job.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Or even simpler, add it to Start up application's menu.